# Hide and Show div based on <a> clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I figured out a way to do this however, there has got to be a cleaner way to do this where it's not so specific and more general. So if I add another link and div, it automatically picks up the association.

```
$(".a1").click(function () {
    $(".div1").show("slow");
    $(".div2").hide("slow");
    $(".div3").hide("slow");
    $(".div4").hide("slow");
    return false; // avoid jump to '#'
});

$(".a2").click(function () {
    $(".div1").hide("slow");
    $(".div2").show("slow");
    $(".div3").hide("slow");
    $(".div4").hide("slow");
           return false; // avoid jump to '#'
});

$(".a3").click(function () {
    $(".div1").hide("slow");
    $(".div2").hide("slow");
    $(".div3").show("slow");
    $(".div4").hide("slow");
           return false; // avoid jump to '#'
});

$(".a4").click(function () {
    $(".div1").hide("slow");
    $(".div2").hide("slow");
    $(".div3").hide("slow");
    $(".div4").show("slow");
           return false; // avoid jump to '#'
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="a1">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="a2">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="a3">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="a4">man, whateva</a>



<div class="div1"  id="div1">Health Research panel</div>
<div class="div2" style="display:none;" id="div2">Healthcare Informatics</div>
<div class="div3" style="display:none;" id="div3" >Public Health informatics</div>
<div class="div4" style="display:none;" id="div4" >Capabilites</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give all the `a` elements the same class, '.link', and all the `div` elements the same class, `.content`, you can use `.index()` to determine the clicked `a` and target the corresponding `div`.

```js
$('.link').on('click', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var index = $('.link').index( this );
  $('.content').filter(':visible').hide().end().eq( index ).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="link">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="link">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="link">man, whateva</a>



<div class="content"  id="div1">Health Research panel</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none;" id="div2">Healthcare Informatics</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none;" id="div3" >Public Health informatics</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none;" id="div4" >Capabilites</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give your divs each an id such as 1_div and a class of div, then you would be able to do something like this:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="1">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" id="2">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" id="3">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" id="4">man, whateva</a>

<div id="1_div" class="div">Health Research panel</div>
<div id="2_div" class="div" style="display:none;" id="div2">Healthcare Informatics</div>
<div id="3_div" class="div" style="display:none;" id="div3" >Public Health informatics</div>
<div id="4_div" class="div" style="display:none;" id="div4" >Capabilites</div>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".div").click(function(){
    var num = $(this).id;
    $(".div").hide('slow');
    $("#"+num+"_div").show('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them all the same class and apply your method:

```
$(".common_class").click(function () {
    $(".div1").hide("slow");
    $(".div2").hide("slow");
    $(".div3").hide("slow");
    $(".div4").show("slow");
           return false; // avoid jump to '#'
});
```

---

Even shorter but needs to assign the show/hide for the divs:

```
$(".common_class").click(function () {
    $(".hide").hide("slow");
    $(".show").show("slow");
           return false; // avoid jump to '#'
});
```

Comment: they were different, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If divs should all be shown or hidden together, they can have a common class that you can use for referencing them together.

Javascript:

```
$(".a4").click(function (){
    $(".showgroup").hide("slow");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div1 showgroup" id="div1"/>
<div class="div2 showgroup" id="div2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global div for your links and your divs and add a data attribute to your links

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/etf154b6/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="#" class="a1" data-id="1">man, whateva</a>
    <a href="#" class="a2" data-id="2">man, whateva</a>
    <a href="#" class="a3" data-id="3">man, whateva</a>
    <a href="#" class="a4" data-id="4">man, whateva</a>
</div> 

<div id="divs">
    <div class="div"  id="div1">Health Research panel</div>
    <div class="div" style="display:none;" id="div2">Healthcare Informatics</div>
    <div class="div" style="display:none;" id="div3" >Public Health informatics</div>
    <div class="div" style="display:none;" id="div4" >Capabilites</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#links a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
            id = $this.data("id");

        $(".div").hide("slow");
        $("#div" + id).show("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[attribute start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** in jquery

```
$("a[class^=a]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var last = this.className.slice(-1);
    $("[class^=div]").hide();
    $(".div" + last).show();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xtz111q3/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers here but rather I would associate link with div through data- attribute. I think it is clear what the association is:

SO my HTML could be:

```
<a href="#" class="a1" data-div="div1">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="a2" data-div="div2">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="a3" data-div="div3">man, whateva</a>
<a href="#" class="a4" data-div="div4">man, whateva</a>


 $(function(){

     $('a').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var that = $(this);

         $('div').hide();
         $('.'+that.attr('data-div')).show();
     });
 });
```

p.s. I am using `a` and `div` here for sake of example. I assume, you would have common class for `<a>`  or `<a>` in a section like `<nav>` or `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a css solution use `pseudo` element `:target`

only thing i have changed is added target for `a` tag and change order of the first div to last so that i can hide the element of click of other target

```css
#div2, #div3, #div4, #div2:target ~ #div1, #div3:target ~ #div1, #div4:target ~ #div1 {
  display: none;
}
#div1:target, #div2:target, #div3:target, #div4:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#div1" class="a1">man, whateva</a>

<a href="#div2" class="a2">man, whateva</a>

<a href="#div3" class="a3">man, whateva</a>

<a href="#div4" class="a4">man, whateva</a>

<div class="div2" id="div2">Healthcare Informatics</div>
<div class="div3" id="div3">Public Health informatics</div>
<div class="div4" id="div4">Capabilites</div>
<div class="div1" id="div1">Health Research panel</div>
```

Comment: Needs to be supported by IE8. Great solution though.